# Game of Life in Java

Tags: java, game-of-life

I wrote John Conway's Game of Life in Java:

```
class GameOfLife {
    static int countSurrounding(int[][] board, int a, int b) {
        int count = 0;
        int[][] surrounding = {{a - 1, b - 1},
                               {a - 1, b    },
                               {a - 1, b + 1},
                               {a    , b - 1},
                               {a    , b + 1},
                               {a + 1, b - 1},
                               {a + 1, b    },
                               {a + 1, b + 1}};
        for (int i[]: surrounding) {
            try {
                if (board[i[0]][i[1]] == 1) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {}
        }
        return count;
    }

    static void printBoard(int[][] board) {
        for (int[] i: board) {
            for (int j: i) {
                if (j == 1) {
                    System.out.print("#");
                }
                else {
                    System.out.print(".");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] nextBoard = {{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
                              {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}};
        int[][] board = new int[nextBoard.length][nextBoard[0].length];
        for (int gen = 0; gen < 25; gen++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nextBoard.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < nextBoard[i].length; j++) {
                    board[i][j] = nextBoard[i][j];
                }
            }
            printBoard(board);
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                    if (board[i][j] == 1 && !(countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 2 || countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 3)) {
                        nextBoard[i][j] = 0;
                    }
                    else if    (board[i][j] == 0 && countSurrounding(board, i, j) == 3) {
                        nextBoard[i][j] = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I improve and optimize it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- Each cell in the Game of Life has exactly two states: *dead* or *alive*. Unless you plan to implement `-1` as *undead*, I'd suggest you use booleans instead of integers to indicate the state.
- The `int i[]` is a bit odd; `i` is normally used for indices, not for whole rows.
- In `countSurrounding` you are using Exceptions to count the surrounding living cells. This is wasteful and unnecessary; we can determine the correct bounds ourself.

  Given an index `i` in an array `row`, we can get the lower index `min` and the upper index `max` by

  ```
  int minRow = i == 0 ? 0 : i - 1;
  int maxRow = i == (row.length - 1) ? (row.length - 1) : i + 1;
  ```

  The same thing for columns (`j` index in an array `column`):

  ```
  int minCol = j == 0 ? 0 : j - 1;
  int maxCol = j == (column.length - 1) ? (column.length - 1) : j + 1;
  ```

  This itself assumes that `i` and `j` always are inside the bounds. We can then loop over the surrounding cells like

  ```
  for (int row_idx = minRow; row_idx <= maxRow; row_idx++) {
     for (int idx = minCol; idx <= maxCol; idx++) {
       if (board[row_idx][idx] && !(row_idx == i && idx == j)) { // assumes board is implemented with booleans
          count++
       }
     }
  }
  ```

  While this is longer, this doesn't abuse exceptions for something totally non-exceptional.
- The `printBoard` is fine, except for my first two criticisms. The `if`/`else` can be condensed to a ternary; I'd find this easier to read:

  ```
  for (boolean row[] : board) {
     for (boolean cell : row) {
        System.out.print( cell ? "#" : "." );
     }
     System.out.println();
  }
  ```
- In `main`, you initialize `nextBoard` with the initial board, then copy it over into `board`. This is slightly useless. I'd propose to refactor your `main` into a method `boolean[][] nextGeneration(boolean[][] board)`. Your `main` would then look like

  ```
  int[][] initialBoard = ...;
  public static void main(String[] args) {
     int[][] board = new int[nextBoard.length][nextBoard[0].length];
     // copy over the initial board
     for (int i = 0; i < initialBoard.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < initalBoard[i].length; j++) {
           board[i][j] = initialBoard[i][j];
        }
     }
     // loop over 25 generations
     printBoard(board);
     for (int gen = 0; gen < 25; gen++) {
        System.out.println("\nGeneration " + gen);
        board = nextGeneration(board);
        printBoard(board);
     }
  }
  ```
- Now something is becoming obvious: We have collected a few static methods that operate on our `board` array. This is a sign that we should create a seperate class:

  ```
  Board
  ========
  - board: boolean[][]
  --------
  - countSurrounding(i: int, j: int): int
  + toString(): String
  + nextGeneration(): Board
  ```

  The class could be easily extended to have a static default board, or a constructor that creates a random board.
- Each “Game of Life” can be described by a ruleset like `23/3`. The digits before the slash determine when a living cell stays alive, the digits after the slash determine when a new cell is born. Generalizing `nextGeneration` to be able to play with all possible rules is a nice exercise.

  ```
  private boolean nextCellState(int i, int j) {
     int count = countSurrounding(i, j);
     int rules[] = board[i][j] ? stayAlive : birthNew;
     for (int rule : rules) {
        if (rule == count) {
           return true;
        }
     }
     return false;
  }
  ```

  then

  ```
  public Board nextGeneration() {
     boolean next[][] = new boolean[board.length][board[0].length];
     int rows = board.length;
     int cols = board.[0].length;
     for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           next[i][j] = nextCellState(i, j);
        }
     }
     return new Board(next);
  }
  ```

Comment: You had my `+1` at "undead". Great example of excessive value spaces.